# Install risc-v tools on mac M1

Tags: apple-m1, riscv

I want to install risc-v tools on my macbook air13' with apple m1 silicon when studying the MITS6.081 lectures and finishing its labs.
I follow this tuto: https://github.com/riscv-software-src/homebrew-riscv.
When I use the command

> brew install riscv-tools

There is an error which seems to be triggered by the unrecognization of 'zifencei'. The part of the error log is as follows. It appears while using the command 'make install'.

```
> make install
> Last 15 lines from /Users/rain/Library/Logs/Homebrew/riscv-pk/02.make:
> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MMD -MP -Wall -Werror -D__NO_INLINE__ -mcmodel=medany -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused -Wno-attributes -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-PIE    -DBBL_LOGO_FILE=\"bbl_logo_file\" -DMEM_START=0x80000000 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DBBL_PAYLOAD=\"bbl_payload\" -I. -I../pk -I../bbl -I../softfloat -I../dummy_payload -I../machine -I../util -c ../machine/uart16550.c
> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MMD -MP -Wall -Werror -D__NO_INLINE__ -mcmodel=medany -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused -Wno-attributes -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-PIE    -DBBL_LOGO_FILE=\"bbl_logo_file\" -DMEM_START=0x80000000 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DBBL_PAYLOAD=\"bbl_payload\" -I. -I../pk -I../bbl -I../softfloat -I../dummy_payload -I../machine -I../util -c ../machine/uart_litex.c
> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MMD -MP -Wall -Werror -D__NO_INLINE__ -mcmodel=medany -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused -Wno-attributes -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-PIE    -DBBL_LOGO_FILE=\"bbl_logo_file\" -DMEM_START=0x80000000 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DBBL_PAYLOAD=\"bbl_payload\" -I. -I../pk -I../bbl -I../softfloat -I../dummy_payload -I../machine -I../util -c ../machine/finisher.c
> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MMD -MP -Wall -Werror -D__NO_INLINE__ -mcmodel=medany -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused -Wno-attributes -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-PIE    -DBBL_LOGO_FILE=\"bbl_logo_file\" -DMEM_START=0x80000000 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DBBL_PAYLOAD=\"bbl_payload\" -I. -I../pk -I../bbl -I../softfloat -I../dummy_payload -I../machine -I../util -c ../machine/misaligned_ldst.c
> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MMD -MP -Wall -Werror -D__NO_INLINE__ -mcmodel=medany -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused -Wno-attributes -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-PIE    -DBBL_LOGO_FILE=\"bbl_logo_file\" -DMEM_START=0x80000000 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DBBL_PAYLOAD=\"bbl_payload\" -I. -I../pk -I../bbl -I../softfloat -I../dummy_payload -I../machine -I../util -c ../machine/flush_icache.c
> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MMD -MP -Wall -Werror -D__NO_INLINE__ -mcmodel=medany -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused -Wno-attributes -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-PIE    -DBBL_LOGO_FILE=\"bbl_logo_file\" -DMEM_START=0x80000000 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DBBL_PAYLOAD=\"bbl_payload\" -I. -I../pk -I../bbl -I../softfloat -I../dummy_payload -I../machine -I../util -c ../machine/mentry.S
> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MMD -MP -Wall -Werror -D__NO_INLINE__ -mcmodel=medany -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused -Wno-attributes -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-PIE    -DBBL_LOGO_FILE=\"bbl_logo_file\" -DMEM_START=0x80000000 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DBBL_PAYLOAD=\"bbl_payload\" -I. -I../pk -I../bbl -I../softfloat -I../dummy_payload -I../machine -I../util -c ../machine/fp_asm.S
> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MMD -MP -Wall -Werror -D__NO_INLINE__ -mcmodel=medany -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused -Wno-attributes -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-PIE    -DBBL_LOGO_FILE=\"bbl_logo_file\" -DMEM_START=0x80000000 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DBBL_PAYLOAD=\"bbl_payload\" -I. -I../pk -I../bbl -I../softfloat -I../dummy_payload -I../machine -I../util -c ../util/snprintf.c
> ../machine/flush_icache.c: Assembler messages:
> ../machine/flush_icache.c:4: Error: unrecognized opcode `fence.i', extension `zifencei' required
> make: *** [flush_icache.o] Error 1
> make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
> ../machine/mentry.S: Assembler messages:
> ../machine/mentry.S:93: Error: unrecognized opcode `fence.i', extension `zifencei' required
> make: *** [mentry.o] Error 1
> 
> If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core):
> https://github.com/riscv-software-src/homebrew-riscv/issues
> 
> These open issues may also help:
> Fix for riscv-pk.rb https://github.com/riscv-software-src/homebrew-riscv/pull/101
```

I find an unclosed issue on github: https://github.com/riscv-software-src/homebrew-riscv/issues/99.
It seems a recent issue. I don't know what does 'zifencei' mean because I am totally new for this.
BTW, I tried to install riscv tools via command

> brew tap riscv/riscv
> brew install riscv-tools

Of course it failed. And I changed it to the command

> brew tap riscv-software-src/riscv
> brew install riscv-tools

Then I faced the problem I have mentioned above.